# Is $\mathfrak{sl}(n,k)$ solvable/nilpotent?

Tags: lie-algebras

I know $\mathfrak{sl}(n,k)$ isn't solvable if char$k\ne2$, and also $\mathfrak{sl}(2,k)$ is nilpotent if char$k=2$. What about $\mathfrak{sl}(n,k)$ when char$k=2$ in general?

Answer (score 1):

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ for $n>1$ is simple over any field of characteristic $p$ if and only if $p\nmid n$. In case of $p\mid n$, the center is nontrivial, but the quotient then by its center is again simple for $n>2$. This "new" simple Lie algebra is denoted by $\mathfrak{psl}_n(K)$ for $p\mid n$.

References:

[Center of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,F)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466361/center-of-mathfraksln-f)

[Is Lie algebra sl(n;F) simple?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904727/is-lie-algebra-slnf-simple)

Comment: What is the relation between simple and solvable/nilpotent?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think you mean the other way round: nilpotent implies solvable but not the converse

Comment: By definition, a simple Lie algebra is not solvable (and hence not nilpotent), and vice versa. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391638/are-semi-simple-lie-algebras-not-solvable) and others at this site.